# Loop failing with Index was outside the bounds of the array in Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a for loop in my code that accesses the web.config file (see code below)

```
 for (int i = 0; i < ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Count; i++)
 {
         string key = cfg.AppSettings.Settings.AllKeys[i];  -- This is line 258 Where it fails
         string value = cfg.AppSettings.Settings[key].Value;
         result.Add(key, value);
 }
```

The Web.config -

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="EmailsLogged" value="True"/>
  <add key="EmailAdminNotification" value="True"/>
  <add key="EmailFrom" value="test@test.com"/>
  <add key="EmailAdminTo" value="test@test.com"/>
  <add key="DataEntryIsEnabled" value="True"/>
  <add key="ViewReportsIsEnabled" value="True"/>
  <add key="ViewOperationsIsEnabled" value="True"/>
  <add key="DownloadDataIsEnabled" value="True"/>
  <add key="ChangeDetailsIsEnabled" value="True"/>
  <add key="PasswordReclaimIsEnabled" value="True"/>
  <add key="RegistrationIsEnabled" value="True"/>
  <add key="SiteIsEnabled" value="True"/>
  <add key="Environment" value="dev"/>
  <add key="ForcePasswordChange" value="true"/>
  <add key="PasswordExpiryInDays" value="90"/>
  <add key="MaxInvalidPasswordAttempts" value="3"/>
  <add key="MinimumOperationDate" value="01/04/2015"/>
</appSettings>
```

This works when run from Visual Studio 2022.  It also works run from IIS.  However when published to an app service in Azure and run I get the following error -

Index was outside the bounds of the array.
at AppConfiguration.GetAppSettings() in c:\home\site\wwwroot\App_Code\Configuration\AppConfiguration.cs:line 258
at Secure_CheckPassword.HasPasswordExpired() in c:\home\site\wwwroot\Secure\CheckPassword.aspx.cs:line 28
at Secure_CheckPassword.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\home\site\wwwroot\Secure\CheckPassword.aspx.cs:line 19
at System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e)
at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

It is using .NET Framework 4.  IT is an old system.

Banging my head of the wall!

Any help would be great!!

Thanks

Comment: what is the connection between "ConfigurationManager.AppSettings" and "cfg.AppSettings"?

Comment: Configuration cfg;
        cfg = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");

Comment: Then forget about looking at the ConfigurationManager. Simply iterate over Settings. Something like `foreach (KeyValueConfigurationElement setting in cfg.AppSettings.Settings)
   result.Add(setting.Key, setting.Value);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string[] keys = cfg.AppSettings.AllKeys;

for (int i = 0; i < keys.Length; i++)
{
    string key = keys[i];
    string value = cfg.AppSettings.Settings[key].Value;
    result.Add(key, value);
}
```

use the `cfg` variable in order to match the count.